# Issue reading file containing Unicode chars using JavaProperties gem

Tags: ruby, unicode, properties

I have mobile automation code in Ruby with locale property files and code is using `JavaProperties::Properties.new(filename with path)` which is returning hash and we are reading property value by providing property name.

Recently **fr_CA.properties** file was updated with unicode chars, something like `"Solde du dernier relev\u00E9"`. After the update, I'm getting value `"Solde du dernier relevÃ©"` instead of `"Solde du dernier relevé"`.

I need some help how/where to provide UTF-8 conversion type.

Quick help highly appreciated.

```
@filePaths={ 
:pathTo_some_JavaProperties => @resourcesPath+"/service_"+locale+""+platform_fileName+".properties", 
:pathTo_locale_other_JavaProperties => @resourcesPath+"/MoblClient_XmlService"+locale+".properties" 
// more file paths 
}

begin 
@someHash = JavaProperties::Properties.new(@filePaths.fetch(:pathTo_some_JavaProperties)) 
rescue Errno::ENOENT 
filesNotFound << @filePaths.fetch(:pathTo_some_JavaProperties)  
end
// Reading value as @someHash['propName'] which is giving output as "Solde du dernier relevÃ©"
```

Comment: Which Ruby version are you using?

Comment: Can you provide a short piece of code which shows the erroneous behaviour?

Comment: My environment is MAC and ruby 2.0.0p353.

Comment: code snippet:

@filePaths={
   :pathTo_some_JavaProperties => @resourcesPath+"/service_"+locale+"_"+platform_fileName+".properties",
   :pathTo_locale_other_JavaProperties => @resourcesPath+"/MoblClient_XmlService_"+locale+".properties"
   // more paths
   }

Comment: begin
   @someHash = JavaProperties::Properties.new(@filePaths.fetch(:pathTo_some_JavaProperties))
  rescue Errno::ENOENT
   filesNotFound << @filePaths.fetch(:pathTo_some_JavaProperties) 
  end
  
  // Reading as @someHash['propName']

Comment: It's unreadable in the comment, please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: I have added code snippet in question section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, here's what I am getting:

In `test.properties`:

```
item1 = Solde du dernier relev\u00E9
```

Then in Ruby,

```
> JavaProperties.load('test.properties')[:item1]
# => "item1 Solde du dernier relevé"
```

You should try getting your problematic code as stripped as possible, and then see if you keep getting the error.

BTW, I think you should use `JavaProperties.load`, not `JavaProperties.new` as in your sample.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.